# Begin dialog with ConnectorClient in Microsoft Bot

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I have an external service which is sending message within following code snippet to Teams chat:

```
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl("serviceUrl");
var appCredentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials("app id", appPassword);
var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient("serviceUrl", appCredentials);
await connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync("conversationId", activity);
```

How can I begin dialog (existing *ComponentDialog* and I can run it inside IBot OnTurnAsync method within *DialogContext*) in same way?

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework 4.2.2.

Comment: Are you saying you want to begin a dialog with a proactive message? What triggers that code? Is there a reason you don't want to update to the latest SDK version?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes, i want to start a Dialog with a proactive message. External API (e.g. ASP.NET Core Controller action method) triggers that code. I don't have any restrictions about SDK version, but there bunch of code written on 4.2.2 yet and I don't want to affect other solutions' parts. Are the any possibility to begin dialog with proactive message in 4.2.2? I have found out sample which is actually using IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, but this type does not appear on 4.2.2

Comment: What parts do you think the newer SDK version will affect? The newer versions are supposed to be backwards compatible.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I've continued working on that and perform migration to 4.9.1. But have faced with another issue which is not resolved yet (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61885871/proactive-waterfall-dialog-dont-continue-in-microsoft-bot). We have changed clarification about that task and now we are sending reminder which is asking user to start dialog by himself. If you have any answers I would be happy to hear any solutions! Thanks!

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't begin a dialog with a connector client. A Bot Framework connector client is only supposed to know about the Bot Framework REST API and isn't supposed to be concerned with any internal bot logic like dialog management.

[Dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog) are based on dialog state which is based on [bot state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state). Bot state is accessed in your configured storage using a specific key. If the type of bot state your dialogs use is user state then the key will be made from the user ID, if it's conversation state then the key will have the conversation ID, and if it's private conversation state then it will have both. This makes sense when you understand that in order to continue a dialog, the bot needs to know the context of the dialog. When the bot reaches step 4 while talking to one user, it shouldn't then start on step 5 when talking to a different user. That's why it's important for it to access the state by using a contextual key.

Normally the information needed to access the right bot state is found in the turn context created by the adapter. The turn context contains the incoming activity which has the user ID in its `from` property and the conversation ID in its `conversation` property. So the real question here is how to access the right bot state when there is no incoming activity, since you're sending a proactive message.

Since you're able to send a message with a connector client, your proactive trigger must have access to the user ID and/or the conversation ID. You can use this information to create a fake incoming activity. You can then run that activity through the adapter like you would for your `api/messages` endpoint, or you can use the activity to construct your own turn context directly. Once you have the turn context, you can make a dialog context out of a dialog set like normal.