# Proactive Waterfall Dialog don't continue in Microsoft Bot

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

There. I am trying to implement Proactive Waterfall dialog to start dialog from external service.

I have implemented `CompoenentDialog` called `SimpleDialogWithCardAndActions`, configured it in `IBot` and now I can start this dialog manually and continue dialog after clicking buttons. It works fine as expected.

Then I have created Controller's action method which is starts proactive dialog

```cs
   private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
              var conversationStateAccessors = conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState));
              var dialogs = new DialogSet(conversationStateAccessors);

              var dialogAccessor = conversationState.CreateProperty<SimpleDialogWithCardAndActionsState>(nameof(SimpleDialogWithCardAndActionsState));
              dialogs.Add(new SimpleDialogWithCardAndActions(dialogAccessor));

              var dc = await dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
              var results = await dc.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
              if (results.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Empty)
              {
                  await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(SimpleDialogWithCardAndActions), null, cancellationToken);
                  await conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(dc.Context, false, cancellationToken);
              }

              await userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
              await conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        }
```

This code successfully executed and display card as expected and I can even tap button and send an activity and handle it in `IBot`, but it does not continue waterfall dialog within `await dc.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);`. I guess that context is lost, but as you can see above, I have saved `ConvesationState` which is also injected to both `IBot` and Controller as a Singletone.

So **my question** is: Is it possible to continue proactive waterfall dialog in `IBot` if it was started within IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter from controller? If it is possible, how can I do that and what I did wrong?

FYI: `IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter` is used only to access `ITurnContext` and start dialog and `IBot` does not use it. Is it possible that I should use same `BotAdapter` instance for both notify Controller and `IBot` implementation?

UPD: I have change Bot-To-Controller binding mechanism and now `IBot` and `NotifyController` are using same singleton `IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter` and that is have **no** effect. **Issue still relevant**

Comment: Hello Herman, do you found any solution? I'm with the same situation... I send a proactive message to the user, which is a waterfall dialog, but the flows doesn't continue to second step after executing the first one.